# Is there one word for both horizontal or vertical, but not diagonal, adjacency?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a grid and I want to say that the adjacent grid square is chosen if it's horizontally or vertically adjacent, but not diagonally adjacent, to the current grid square.

I was thinking maybe, laterally adjacent?

Comment: Contiguous, if the two diagonal squares are not touching.

Comment: Fails the "one word" criterion, but considering the question I think of the word perpendicular, as well as the phrase "cardinally adjacent" (that is, adjacent in a cardinal direction).

Comment: @KCH *contiguous* does not seem to match: **contiguous** *being in actual contact : touching along a boundary or at a point* (from m-w.com)

Comment: Not that I know of. [Orthogonally adjacent](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all#hl=en&q=%22orthogonally+adjacent%22) is used.

Comment: I'm just here wondering about what to call pieces that move like rooks for my chess engine. :-)

Comment: +1 for "Laterally Adjacent" that's what I'm going with :)

Comment: You see this a lot in puzzles and games, where a good puzzle compiler almost always says what they mean by "adjacent" (whether it includes or excludes diagonals). The question should be "how can I best be understood?" not "is there an obscure word that can save me a few characters' typing?"

Comment: These questions kill me. How can two opposite things have one word to describe both together? Is that a word to describe UP and DOWN together??

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51206/are-there-names-for-the-different-types-of-adjacency-in-a-square-grid

Answer (score 18):

I've seen both "Orthogonally Adjacent" (Adjacent at right angles) and "Edge Adjacent" (Adjacent across edges rather than corners) used.  They do mean slightly different things, but it's only relevant when dealing with something other than a regular rectangular grid.

Since measuring distance in this kind of topology is called "Manhattan distance" you might also try "Manhattan adjacent" although I've never seen that usage myself and it would probably require some explanation before using it.

Comment: You must be a programmer too :) Thanks for this, I think I'll use edge adjacent.

Comment: Do you have any references or sources for "Edge Adjacent"? I'm looking, but cannot find any.

Comment: I found several when searching on Google for `"edge adjacent" "corner adjacent"` This PDF about Quadtree colouring makes the distinction in those terms http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/9907030.pdf

Answer (score 8):

Consider **Orthogonal**

> [Orthogonal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthogonal) - intersecting or lying at right angles

Comment: But the two diagonals are also orthogonal to each other.

Comment: @WanderingLogic I still think it makes sense, because the diagonals are not orthogonal to the grid, but you make a good point.

Comment: This would answer the original *title* of the question, which only specified synonyms for "horizontal" and "vertical" -- they're all *directions*. There can be many cells that are orthogonal, but not necessarily neighboring/touching.

Answer (score 5):

Abut: an area that is next to and has a common boundary with.

His land abuts mine

Comment: But the answer should be an adjective :-) ... *abutting*

Answer (score 4):

Please consider:

> **bor·der** noun : a line separating one country or state from another; a boundary between places

(or *bordering*)

*from m-w.com*

Geospatially (not necessesarily mathematically) anything that was diagonal would share a point, which is commonly considered not a line.  *E.g. Utah borders Colorado and Arizona but not New Mexico.*

Comment: I sort of agree that bordering might be a good word to replace "adjacent" but you have to be careful with your last sentence. In geometry, the three undefined terms are point, line, and plane. Most math folks are comfortable with the common definitions but it's still considered taboo to say they have been defined and to compare those definitions.

Comment: @jboneca Point taken; I've edited as appropriate.

Comment: Your example is [technically incorrect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Corners_Monument) in so far as there is a point of Utah that touches a point of New Mexico, thus placing them at each other’s border. I suggest you choose a correct example.

Comment: @tchrist -- the example perfectly mirrors the OP's question. You may disagree that *bordering* is an appropriate word choice, but the example is not badly chosen.

Comment: Border (horizontal and vertical) vs Edge (diagonal) seems like a nice pairing of terminology to me. Otherwise said as `border adjacent` vs `edge adjacent`.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, I like the term **axial** to describe a direction that is along the horizontal or vertical axis relative to the current position.

[Axial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/axial) - situated around, in the direction of, on, or along an axis.

Comment: Axial as opposed to what? Is there another name for diagonal so they pair well?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to say that the adjacent grid square is chosen if it's horizontally or vertically adjacent, but not diagonally adjacent to the current grid square, why not say that it's "[nondiagonally adjacent](http://www.dragonheelslair.com/en/rulesalea.php)?"

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best term is [*rectilinearly adjacent*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rectilinearly+adjacent%22).  Compared to *orthogonal*, *rectilinear* has a stronger connotation of being axially aligned.

Comment: I'd say "squarely adjacent" rather than any of  rectilinearly, orthogonally, or  nondiagonally adjacent

Answer (score 1):

Also consider

> **coterminous** or **conterminous**: having the same or coincident boundaries

essentially, synonymous with *bordering*.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct usage of "coterminous". Regions that border have *part* of a boundary in common, but I think "coterminous" means that the *entire* border is the same; that is, the two entities comprise the same region. Queens (the borough of New York City) is coterminous with Queens County (a county in New York); they're arguably not the same thing, but they have the same borders and they comprise the same region.

Comment: @TannerSwett -- That is another meaning (one i only discovered today) of coterminous. The other meaning is to share part of a boundary. See http://www.onelook.com/?w=coterminous&ls=a

Answer (score 0):

It's not one word, and I'm not sure how many people would follow it, but from cellular automata, you could refer to "squares that are *in the von Neumann neighborhood* of the current square".

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read the Wikipedia article about [pixel connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity).

The case you describe is called *4-connectivity*, so the adjective you seek is *4-connected*.

Answer (score 0):

You can also say they are **cardinally adjacent**.

The [cardinal directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction) are North, South, East and West, which conventionally map to up, down, right and left in 2D images. A Google search for the term "[cardinally adjacent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cardinally%20adjacent%22)" has about 7,500 results at the time of writing, so this is a somewhat common term, although "[orthogonally adjacent](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22orthogonally%20adjacent%22)" has about 25,000, making it about three times as common.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the word "lateral" to describe this. It's defined as "Of , relating to, or situated at or on the side"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Grids in the form of algebraic matrices are ubiquitous in machine learning and statistical models, with many ways to describe the resulting relationships.

One drawback to their use is that the distances between the cells of a grid are typically fixed.

Network models are one approach to compensating for this fixity insofar as relative distances are approximated based on the function used...with the caveat that there are literally dozens of distance metrics, most orthogonal (not correlated) and others oblique (allows for correlation).

I can't find a specific example of terminology which answers your query but the field is rife with possibilities.

Check out this IBM white paper for an intro but note that network models are a large and burgeoning area of study.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-modeler/18.0.0?topic=analysis-about-social-network